# how to count specific rows based on data in table fields for pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, pagination

I'm have a database with users from different countries. My pagination is working because the query counts all rows. So it gives you like 5 pages and let's say the total records are finished by page3.

My question is:

1) How can I count only records from one country let's say "australia"? And the pagination should only give me pages with results no extra pages with no results?

My code for pagination is below:

```
        <?php

       $per_page = 1;
       $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`");
        $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query,0)/$per_page);

        if (!isset($_GET['page']))

        {
          header("location: blood.php?page=1");

        }
        else

          {
           $page = $_GET['page'];

          }

          $start = (($page - 1)*$per_page);

          $colours = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE country ='australia'   LIMIT $start,$per_page");

          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($colours))
          {
             $username = $row['first_name'];

            echo "$username<br>";

          }

          for($number=1; $number<=$pages; $number++)
          {
             echo '<a href= "?page='.$number.'">'.$number.'&nbsp;</a>';
             echo"&nbsp;";
          }

         echo "<br>Current Page: $page";
      ?>
```

how do i include the above code together with the correction suggested in the below code where results are returned after user searches for a username and lastname.

```
      <?php 

      include 'core/init.php'; 
      include 'includes/overall/oheader.php';
      ?>

       <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
        $query = $_POST['uname_search'];
        $queryl = $_POST ['lname_search'];

        $min_length = 3;
       if(strlen($query) >= $min_length && strlen($queryl) >= $min_length)
      {
        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        $queryl = htmlspecialchars($queryl);
         $queryl = mysql_real_escape_string($queryl);
      echo "<table border='1' width='250px' align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>";
    echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#002C40' style='color:#FFF'>
    <td height='30px' width='150px'>Username</td> <td>first_name</td>    <td>last_name</td><td>email</td><td>Mobile_Number</td><td>gender</td><td>county</td><td>blood_group</td>


  $raw_results =

    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`username` LIKE  '%".$query."%') AND (`last_name` LIKE '%".$queryl."%')");
     if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0)
    {
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
    {

     $image = "images/profile/1a4671c319.jpg" ; 

     echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#002C40' style='color:#FFF'>


    <td rowspan='4'>"."<img src=".$results['profile']." width=100px  height=100px> "."</td>
    <td >Username</td>
    <td >first_name</td>
    <td>last_name</td>
    <td>email</td>


    </tr>";

     echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#0f7ea3'>
      <td>".$results['username']."</td> 
     <td>".$results['first_name']."</td> 
     <td>".$results['last_name']."</td> 
     <td>".$results['email']."</td> 

     </tr>" ;

    echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#002C40' style='color:#FFF'>




     <td>Mobile_Number</td>
     <td>gender</td>
     <td>county</td>
     <td>blood_group</td>

     </tr>";

      echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#0f7ea3'>

      <td>".$results['Mobile_Number']."</td> 
       <td>".$results['gender']."</td> 
      <td>".$results['county']."</td> 
      <td>".$results['blood_group']."</td> 

     </tr>" ;
    }

   }
    else{
     echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#6C0000'>

       <td colspan='8' height='25px'>No results</td><tr>";
    echo "</table>";
     }
    }
    else{
       echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
     }

      }

       include 'includes/overall/ofooter.php';

     ?>
```

Comment: Why you need `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"` at all? I can only imagine so a query if you want to show `14 users from Australia / 100 users in total` alike messages

Comment: how do i include the variable if im letting the user to search. i tried the following but its giving me only 1 result instead of 3 and no links to other pages. ``mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE country =" . $country . " ");``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply the same `where` clause to the first query which counts the users:

```
$pages_query = 
    mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE country ='australia'");
    # Here -----------------------------------^
```

Comment: what if i am taking in the country from a user search page and storing in php variable $country. how would i include it in the query. i tried the following but its not giving me results. it should show 1 result then show me links to other pages. iits not doing that.  **mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE country =" . $country . " ");**